# Fetch website HTML, then find & copy columns and rows: PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm fetching the entire HTML code of a website using file_get_contents and saving it into a variable.

The content of this website is time-based and updates frequently. I need to run a script that will fetch specific columns and rows from its HTML which I then plan to turn into human-readable text form.

My problem now is that I have little knowledge of what method I should use to scan the HTML, find the columns and rows I'm looking to extract and only save it if there has been an update to it since the previous time the script was run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with DOM traversal, try using [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php). Then use the other [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) methods to get at the information you need.

Here is some example xml:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- test.html -->
<html><body>
    <table id = "target_table"><tbody>
        <tr><td>this</td><td>something</td></tr>
        <tr><td>is</td><td>in</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>a</td></tr>
        <tr><td>test</td><td>column</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <table><tbody>
        <tr><td>ignore</td><td>this</td></tr>
        <tr><td>table</td><td>.</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
</body></html>
```

This will grab all of the rows in a specific table and dump their text content:

```php
<?php

$string = file_get_contents("test.html");
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($string);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//*[@id=\"target_table\"]/*/tr");

foreach ($elements as $element) {
  echo $element->textContent, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: ```<?php

//Loading HTML from URL
$html = file_get_contents('');


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = '';
foreach($xpath->evaluate('') as $childNode) {
  $result .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
}
//var_dump($result);

?>
```

I got this much, and it worked. 

2 questions now:

how can I add more than 1 Xpath? The array looks a bit confusing and I need help with that.

Also, what if the results in the table are updated, will the xpath change at all?

Comment: Your questions are specific to the html you are trying to digest. I don't know if I can answer your second question without seeing the source html. If you want more than one xpath, maybe you need to use wildcards or run the query with a different selector?

Comment: if you found my answer helpful could you throw me an upvote or accept :) Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you definitely got me started. Thanks.